# Kubernetes : pod parameters depending on replica

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking on how can I change the parameter of containers depending on the number of replica ?

For example, I would like to have an environment variable ( which is the name of my hubot)  as follow :

1. First Replica : Name1
2. Second replica : Name2...

Do you have an idea of how can I achieve that ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The feature is called "[StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset)" in Kubernetes. Have a look at the [Stable Network ID](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id) section in particular.

Stateful sets are available in Kubernetes 1.5. If you need an older version, you could use some kind of central registry like [redis](https://redis.io/commands/incr) instead and implement some logic where new pods request the next free number when they start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I will look for redis and try it :)